# I want to position the left image position set to sticky

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to set the left image of https://asleshifa.com/product/t500-smart-watch/
Like this
https://sundaypk.com/product/t500-smart-watch/

I have tried

```css
.storefront-full-width-content.single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery {
    width: 42.130435%;
    margin-right: 1.347826%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this media query to the CSS:

```
  @media (min-width: 900px){
    .site{overflow-x: visible;}
  }
```

Comment: it worked thanks alot.